# Who gives a consent for data publication?

Tags: postdocs

I spent a year in a foreign country. Now I am at home.

The problem is that my advisor and me did not prepare any research publication. My project was to arrange for some experiments which my advisor wanted to publish together with the other researchers' experiment. These researchers are not in the advisor institution.

I finished my job successfully but the second party did not (their explanations are like they are not satisfied with the results). My input looks publishable as a separate paper but my advisor does not give their consent. Despite almost a year passed from the initial deadline of our coworkers, they are unable to contribute.

Is there anything I can do to publish the results of my own work?

Please do not suggest writing regular reminders, I do this routinely, however, it seems that this project is not on the top of the priority list of anyone except myself. Sorry to be verbose...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking. What do you mean by "a publication documenting your stay in the foreign country"? Just "I didn't publish anything while I was there"?

Comment: What reason does your advisor give for the holdup? Does he hope "second party" will provide better data in the future? Is someone else working on closing the gaps? Is any work done on the project at all? Is he applying for funding to get the rest of the work done? Does he wish to give up the paper entirely? I think clarifying this question is essential for a response.

Comment: @ Captain Emacs : The advisor does not look interested. The explanations are "let's wait" or "I understand you, I will settle the matter with the coworkers", but nothing happens during almost a year. The advisor has other papers in preparation and does not seem to worry about my project.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have too many options except keeping your advisor busy about it. There are some universities apply the rule that if the data do not get published in 2 years or so the advisor can publish it wihtout the consent of the student. However in your situation you don't have right something like that. On the other hand, if you persuade your advisor that you are willing to publish a paper using only your data you may get your advisor's consent. Good Luck

Comment: The advisor has my manuscript at hand. But he does not submit it. Sometimes he agrees that we should submit alone and promises to submit soon. But actually he does not.